# Binary Tree "behavior"

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have the following binary search tree (in C++) and i have a question to a specific line of code :

```
delete k;
```

My code is working if i remove that line , and I don't understand why.
By my understanding : the data from k is being inserted into the tree and THEN then the variable k is deleted.
Why is the data deleting from the Tree too?

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct nod
{
nod *st=NULL;
int info;
nod *dr=NULL;
int h;
nod *par=NULL;       // par = "father"
};
struct avl     
{
nod *rad=NULL;                  //rad = root;
void insert(nod *z)             //INSERT
{
    nod *y = NULL;
    nod *x = rad;
    while (x != NULL)
    {
        y = x;
        if (z->info < x->info)
        {
            x = x->st;         // st = left
        }
        else
        {
            x = x->dr;        //dr = right
        }
    }
    if (y == NULL)
    {
        rad = z;
    }
    else
    {
        if (z->info < y->info)
        {
            y->st = z;
        }
        else
        {
            y->dr = z;
        }
    }
    z->par = y;
}
void inordine(nod *k)
{
    if (k)
    {
        inordine(k->st);
        cout << k->info<<"\t";
        inordine(k->dr);
    }
}
};
int main(void)
{
avl *arbore = new avl;
int el = 5;
arbore->rad=NULL;
while (el >= 0)
{
    cout << "element\n";
    cin >> el;
        nod *k = new nod;
        k->dr = NULL;
        k->st = NULL;
        k->par = NULL;
        k->info = el;
        arbore->insert(k);
        delete k;
}
cout << "print inordine\n";
arbore->inordine(arbore->rad);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the data from k is being inserted into the tree and THEN then the variable k is deleted

No, k is just a pointer. It points to a nod(e). You are inserting this node into your tree (by passing it as a pointer). It is not a copy, it is that same node. delete does not delete a variable, it deletes the node, so you are also removing it from your tree.

A big argument against raw pointers like you are using, is that it is difficult to express who is the owner of the object. This is evidence supporting that argument. You were expecting that the tree owned its nodes, your program shows the opposite behavior.

To properly dispose of the nodes you would need a destructor that traverses the tree and deletes each node upon the destruction of the tree. You would also need to hide the actual nodes from your trees users by using inserts like `avl::insert(int info, int h);`